# how to remove search box when click outside element but not remove when click inside (special input and button)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a search box like this code.
When I click outside the search box, I want it to close.
But in my code, when I click on Input for writing or the content inside the search box, the search box closes.

Could you guide me to where my code is wrong?

Thank you in advance for your cooperation.

```js
const searchIcon = document.querySelector("#searchIcon");
const searchContent = document.querySelector( ".searchForm--content");
searchIcon.addEventListener("click", function() {
    searchContent.classList.toggle("active");
});


window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('#searchIcon') ) {    
   var searchContent=document.querySelector(".searchForm--content");
     var searchFormInput=document.querySelector("searchForm--content.active > .searchForm--content__input");
     if(searchContent.classList.contains('active') && !event.target.contains(searchFormInput)){
          searchContent.classList.remove('active');
      }
  }
}
```

```css
.searchForm--content{
    position: relative
}

#searchIcon{
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px;
  width: fit-content;
}

.searchForm > img {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.searchForm--content{
  border: 1px solid blue;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding-inline:0.75rem;
  color: black;
  position: absolute;
  left: 12px;
  width: 40%;
  top: 70px;
  display: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.searchForm--content.active {
  display: flex;
} 

.searchForm--content .btn{
    position: absolute;
    left:0.2rem;
    top:50%;
    transform: translatey(-50%);
}
.searchForm--content input[type="search"]{
    width: 65%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 1rem 0.5rem;
    color: black;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<form class="searchForm" role="search">
  <div id="searchIcon">my icon search</div>
  
    <div class="searchForm--content" id="my-box">
        <input type="search" placeholder="search" name="s" inputmode="search"  class="searchForm--content__input" /> 
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn--blue" >submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I have updated the code in the answer. Try that

Comment: If the answer resolve the problem, mark it as correct for future visitors. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that whenever you click on an element, the `click` event fires for not only that element, but also all of its parent elements. So, a `click` event handler on `window` will fire for any click anywhere on the page.

To stop a `click` event from going to other event handlers like this, you can call the [`event.stopImmediatePropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopImmediatePropagation) method. Just use it like this:

```js
const searchIcon = document.querySelector("#searchIcon");
const searchContent = document.querySelector(".searchForm--content");
searchIcon.addEventListener("click", function() {
  searchContent.classList.toggle("active");
});

searchContent.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.stopImmediatePropagation();
});

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('#searchIcon')) {
    var searchContent = document.querySelector(".searchForm--content");
    var searchFormInput = document.querySelector("searchForm--content.active > .searchForm--content__input");
    if (searchContent.classList.contains('active') && !event.target.contains(searchFormInput)) {
      searchContent.classList.remove('active');
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.searchForm--content {
  position: relative
}

#searchIcon {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px;
  width: fit-content;
}

.searchForm>img {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.searchForm--content {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding-inline: 0.75rem;
  color: black;
  position: absolute;
  left: 12px;
  width: 40%;
  top: 70px;
  display: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.searchForm--content.active {
  display: flex;
}

.searchForm--content .btn {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0.2rem;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translatey(-50%);
}

.searchForm--content input[type="search"] {
  width: 65%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 1rem 0.5rem;
  color: black;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<form class="searchForm" role="search">
  <div id="searchIcon">my icon search</div>

  <div class="searchForm--content" id="my-box">
    <input type="search" placeholder="search" name="s" inputmode="search" class="searchForm--content__input" />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn--blue">submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this that you are just **matching the div with id searchIcon**. So, when you click that div, the search Form Content show. But when you click on search input field, it close the search Form Content, because you are **not matching search input field in if condition**. So, you have to update the if condition. Here is the updated answer:-

```js
const searchIcon = document.querySelector("#searchIcon");
const searchContent = document.querySelector( ".searchForm--content");
searchIcon.addEventListener("click", function() {
    searchContent.classList.toggle("active");
});


window.onclick = function(event) {
  console.log(event.target.matches('#searchIcon'))
  if (!(event.target.matches('#searchIcon') ||  event.target.matches('.searchForm--content__input'))) {    
   var searchContent=document.querySelector(".searchForm--content");
     var searchFormInput=document.querySelector("searchForm--content.active > .searchForm--content__input");
     if(searchContent.classList.contains('active') && !event.target.contains(searchFormInput)){
          searchContent.classList.remove('active');
      }
  }
}
```

```css
.searchForm--content{
    position: relative
}

#searchIcon{
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px;
  width: fit-content;
}

.searchForm > img {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.searchForm--content{
  border: 1px solid blue;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding-inline:0.75rem;
  color: black;
  position: absolute;
  left: 12px;
  width: 40%;
  top: 70px;
  display: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.searchForm--content.active {
  display: flex;
} 

.searchForm--content .btn{
    position: absolute;
    left:0.2rem;
    top:50%;
    transform: translatey(-50%);
}
.searchForm--content input[type="search"]{
    width: 65%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 1rem 0.5rem;
    color: black;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<form class="searchForm" role="search">
  <div id="searchIcon">my icon search</div>
  
    <div class="searchForm--content" id="my-box">
        <input type="search" placeholder="search" name="s" inputmode="search"  class="searchForm--content__input" /> 
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn--blue" >submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

In this way, when you click **submit button**, it will close the search Form content. That's good. So, only **clicking on search field and div with id searchIcon will not close the searchForm content**.

Answer (score 1):

Your condition in the `EventListener` doesn't check at all whether your `click` happened inside the textbox. You're only checking for `#searchIcon`.

Updated snippet:

```js
const searchIcon = document.querySelector("#searchIcon");
const searchContent = document.querySelector(".searchForm--content");
searchIcon.addEventListener("click", function() {
  searchContent.classList.toggle("active");
});


window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!(event.target.closest('#searchIcon') || event.target.closest('#my-box'))) {
    var searchContent = document.querySelector(".searchForm--content");
    var searchFormInput = document.querySelector(
      "searchForm--content.active > .searchForm--content__input");
    if (searchContent.classList.contains('active') && !event.target.contains(searchFormInput)) {
      searchContent.classList.remove('active');
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.searchForm--content {
  position: relative
}

#searchIcon {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px;
  width: fit-content;
}

.searchForm>img {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.searchForm--content {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding-inline: 0.75rem;
  color: black;
  position: absolute;
  left: 12px;
  width: 40%;
  top: 70px;
  display: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.searchForm--content.active {
  display: flex;
}

.searchForm--content .btn {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0.2rem;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translatey(-50%);
}

.searchForm--content input[type="search"] {
  width: 65%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 1rem 0.5rem;
  color: black;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<form class="searchForm" role="search">
  <div id="searchIcon">my icon search</div>

  <div class="searchForm--content" id="my-box">
    <input id="inputSearch" type="search" placeholder="search" name="s" inputmode="search" class="searchForm--content__input" />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn--blue">submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Notice that I used `event.target.closest` instead of `matches` so that the it checks against `#my-box` and all of its children so you don't need to worry about checking against each element in that area. Got inspiration for that from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56803429/13927534) by @AuxTaco

Comment: Normally search field work with ajax so that we show the content dynamically. In that case, if user click submit, it will not close the search form content. So, binding with all children, not good. Instead checking only search input field and the button that show the search form content is good. Because in this way, clicking on submit button will also automatically close the search Form Content.

Comment: @Developer yeah I see your point, realistically it can be replaced with `matches` if OP prefers, I mostly meant to showcase this option in case they weren't aware of it and could potentially be useful for them. I appreciate the input though, thanks :)